# Canonical setup of Gradle Build

Tags: java, python, gradle

I want to set up a large-ish project, and I'm told that gradle is the way to do it.

I'm very confused by Gradle, and the entire system seems like a lot of magic, hand-waving, and knowledge that I don't want to read all 60 chapters of the Gradle guide to grok.

I'm going to end up with the following components:

- ProtoBuf files defining a bunch of messages
- Java Library 1 and tests (dependent on the ProtoBufs)
- Java Library 2 and tests (dependent on Java Library 1)
- Java Applications (dependent on Java Library 2)
- Android Application (dependent on Java Library 2)
- iOS Application
- Duplicates of all of the Java stuff, but for Python, C++, and Objective-C)

I want to be able to build and test everything in one large shot.  So normally I'd build a tree like this:

```
project/ proto/
         lib1/ java/   src/
                       test/
               python/ src/
                       test/
               ...
         lib2/ java/   src/
                       test/
               python/ src/
                       test/
               ...
         app1/ java/   src/
                       test/
               python/ src/
                       test/
               ...
         app2/ java/   src/
                       test/
               python/ src/
                       test/
               ...
         android/ src/
                  test/
         iOS/ src/
              test/
```

I get that build iOS from gradle might not be possible, so I'm happy to ignore it for now.

Is this an appropriate structure to use?  How do I structure and place my gradle.build files so that libraries can be used by other teams properly?  How do I make sure my dependencies are tight so that libraries include only the minimum set of what they need to include?

Gradle build files seem to leave a bunch of potentially unused tasks littered around.  Do I just try to ignore these?

Answer (score 0):

The structure I resided on was based on grouping similar projects into subproject structures.

```
project/client/core/common-android
project/client/core/features-android
project/client/core/ui-android
project/client/app/client-android
project/server/admin
project/server/base
project/server/util
project/server/api-deployment
project/bundles/bundle1
project/bundles/bundle2
project/bundles/bundle3
project/bundles/bundle4
```

This structure make using subproject much more intuitive then flat directory structures.  Now we can apply configurations to the subproject that are similar.  My final project structure looks like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'platform'
+--- Project ':client' - Client: Android core projects
|    +--- Project ':client:common-android' - Client: Common library for Android aar
|    +--- Project ':client:features-android' - Client: Features library for Android aar
|    +--- Project ':client:ui-android' - Client: UI library for Android aar
|    +--- Project ':client:app-android' - Client: Apk client Android apk
+--- Project ':bundles' - bundles: OSGi bundles container project
|    +--- Project ':bundles:bundle1' - bundles: OSGi bundle jar
|    +--- Project ':bundles:bundle2' - bundles: OSGi bundle jar
|    +--- Project ':bundles:bundle3' - bundles: OSGi bundle jar
|    +--- Project ':bundles:bundle4' - bundles: OSGi bundle jar
\--- Project ':server' - Server: Coriolis root project
     +--- Project ':server:admin' - Server: admin jar
     +--- Project ':server:base' - Server: jar base
     +--- Project ':server:apiDeployment' - Server: platform deployment war
     \--- Project ':server:util' - Server: utils jar
```

Since we don't want the parent projects to know as little as possible about their children we can let each grouping of projects configure itself during configuration via the `settings.gradle`

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'platform'

Map<String, String> projectProperties = startParameter.getProjectProperties()
projectProperties.put('platform', true.toString())

// TODO: Make project imports smarter by removing hardcoding of paths

def subprojects = settingsDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory() && (file.name == 'client' || file.name == 'server')
    }
})

for (File file : subprojects) {
    println "Found subproject directory: $file.absolutePath"
    switch (file.name) {
        case 'client':
            def androidHome = 'ANDROID_HOME'
            // any non-null value will add android modules to the build.
            // Assumption is only a valid SDK location will be set.
            if (System.getenv(androidHome)) {
                def clientFile = new File("$file.absolutePath/core/childProjectSettings.gradle")
                if (clientFile.exists()) {
                    println "Adding android client"
                    include ':client'
                    project(":client").projectDir = clientFile.parentFile
                    apply from: clientFile.absolutePath
                }
            } else {
                println "WARNING: Environment variable {$androidHome} not set.  Not adding Android modules as they are " +
                        "impossible to build without the Android SDK being installed.  To install the Android SDK " +
                        "please see: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html"
            }
            break
        case 'server':
            def serverFile = new File("$file.absolutePath/server/childProjectSettings.gradle")
            if (serverFile.exists()) {
                println "Adding server"
                include ':server'
                project(':server').projectDir = serverFile.parentFile
                apply from: serverFile.absolutePath
            }

            def bundlesFile = new File("$file.absolutePath/bundles/childProjectSettings.gradle")
            if (bundlesFile.exists() && !projectProperties.containsKey('noBundles')) {
                println "Adding osgi bundles"
                include ':bundles'
                project(':bundles').projectDir = bundlesFile.parentFile
                apply from: bundlesFile.absolutePath
            }
            break
        default:
            println "Unknown subproject found: $file.absolutePath"
    }
}
```

Now only subprojects that exist on the disk will be included, we can remove the remaining hardcoding for a more dynamic example but this is simpler.  Then we create a file (in this example) `childProjectSettings.gradle` for each of our project groupings (client, server, bundles).  Your `childProjectSettings.gradle` should specify it's subprojects in a way that it doesn't need to be updated every time a new subproject is added.

childProjectSettings.gradle:

```
File moduleSettingsDir = new File("$settingsDir.absolutePath/server", "bundles")

println "Bundles sees settings dir as: $moduleSettingsDir.absolutePath"

def bundleDirectories = moduleSettingsDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.isDirectory()
    }
})

// get a reference to this project's descriptor so we can add subprojects
ProjectDescriptor bundles = project(':bundles')

bundleDirectories.each { File bundleDir ->
    if (new File(bundleDir, "build.gradle").exists()) {
        // normalize project names (blah-blah -> blahBlah)
        def bundleName = bundleDir.name
        if (bundleName.contains("-")) {
            def names = bundleDir.name.split("-")
            bundleName = names[0] + names[1].capitalize()
        }

        // include a subproject in the build
        include ":bundles:$bundleName"
        // default location will be wrong lets update the project's directory
        project(":bundles:$bundleName").projectDir = bundleDir
        // add the project as a subproject giving us better grouping
        bundles.children.add(project(":bundles:$bundleName"))
    }
}

project(':bundles').children.each {
    println "Parent {$it.parent} found child {$it} in path {$it.path} using buildScript {$it.buildFile $it.path}"
}
```

> Gradle build files seem to leave a bunch of potentially unused tasks littered around. Do I just try to ignore these?

It's not the build files that create the tasks it's the plugins that are applied in the `build.gradle` files.  To keep the tasks as tight as possible then only declare plugins in the `build.gradle` that it's actually used.  Tasks are not inherited from dependency projects but declared dependencies are inherited from dependency projects.

*There is an important note here all dependencies are `transitive` by default so if `ui` depends on `core` which declares the `gson` dependency then `ui` will by default have `gson` in it's classpath.

For your question about the source folders a more gradle structure would probably look more like the below.  Where your groups of apps would be `lib1:java|lib1:python|lib2:java|lib2:python|app1:java|app1:python|app2:java|app2:python` each of theses would be a subproject of their containing group.

Then `lib1` project contains two subproject `lib1:java` and `lib1:python` each compiled with the plugins in their own `build.gradle` files.  Common code can be placed in a custom plugin in the `buildSrc` if needed.

```
project/ proto/
         lib1/ java/   src/main/java/
                       src/main/javaTest/
               python/ src/main/python/
                       src/main/pythonTest/
               ...
         lib2/ java/   src/main/java/
                       src/main/javaTest/
               python/ src/main/python/
                       src/main/pythonTest/
               ...
         app1/ java/   src/main/java/
                       src/main/javaTest/
               python/ src/main/python/
                       src/main/pythonTest/
               ...
         app2/ java/   src/main/java/
                       src/main/javaTest/
               python/ src/main/python/
                       src/main/pythonTest/
               ...
         android/ src/
                  test/
         iOS/ src/
              test/
```